# How to check if an element is of a particular style in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-selectors

I have an element:

```
  #credit-card{:style => user.has_stripe_customer_id? ? "display:none" : "display:block"}
       .input
           = text_field_tag :credit_card_number, params[:credit_card_number], :class => "field"
       .actions
         = f.submit("Buy Gift")
```

How should I write a jQuery selector to check if #credit-card is in "display:none" or not? I tried

```
if($('#credit-card').hasClass('display:none')) {
            $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true);
        }
```

But it doesn't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) pseudoselector (if it is specific enough):

```
if($('#credit-card').is(":hidden")) { .. }
```

Or, if that's not specific enough, you could examine the CSS `display` property using [`.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css):

```
if ($('#credit-card').css('display') === 'none') { .. }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if($('#credit-card').hasClass('display:none'))  "display:none" is NOT a class!!! display_none is a class
```